# Stop prompting experienced users about upvoting "both the question and the answers up"

Tags: feature-request

I keep getting this pop-up every now and then:

> Welcome back!
> If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.
>
> close this message

A pop-up is a pop-up; it's annoying.

For new users and/or those who never click the vote buttons, I get that this pop-up might be a good idea. But given that I am an experienced user who frequently upvotes useful questions and answers, could I please *not* be targeted by this popup?

I even have the Electorate badge (Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.), I know upvoting is nice.

Maybe not seeing this pop-up could be a privilege that comes with the badge?

Or just don't show if user upvoted X% questions in the last X days?

Comment: I've never noticed this popup, maybe it's A/B testing?

Comment: Tbh I don't mind it at all, I occasionally forget to upvote good answers which have helped me so I like to be reminded.

Comment: We need one to remind people to downvote incorrect/low quality questions/answers.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny no, it exists for years now.

Comment: The message will only appear if you  haven't voted recently. The best way to not see it, is to keep voting, regardless how much you voted in the past.

Comment: Assuming it hasn't changed since 2011 (which is possible), [here's the list of criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059). It's apparently only supposed to trigger when you enter a site from a search engine where you 1) already have an account and 15+ rep on that site, 2) haven't been active on that site in 24 hours, and 3) have never voted on the particular Q&A page you land on.

Comment: This is also essentially an exact dupe of [Request reduced instances of displaying the "Don't forget to upvote the question and the answers" overlay for users with sufficiently high rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363769)

Comment: I have good rep and I vote a lot, and I still see this message (and a similar one) rather frequently (at least once per batch of 100 votes). It's been the same for years.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91553/i-see-welcome-back-if-you-found-this-question-useful-message-very-frequent/154961#154961